# rpi pico: How to detect that sys.stdout is connected

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I am using a rpi pico to collect temperature measurements which are saved to a local file.
I additionally want,when the pico is connected via usb to PC, to output them on stdout. I have tried this:

```
f=open('temps.txt','a+')
while True:
  temps=getTemperatures()
  f.write(temps)
  print(temps)
```

If the `print(temps)` line is commented out, measurements are collected as long as pico is powered, whether or not the PC is on or in standby. But with the `print` line uncommented, measurements are saved only if the PC is on. It seems the `print` blocks waiting for the connection to be re-established. How can I detect that the connection is active, so that `print` is executed only when it will not block?

Comment: The thread [Re: Timed input routine not working](https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=9823&p=55001&hilit=stdout+timeout#p55029) in the micropython forum seems to imply that there is no way of doing this. I think I will have to rely on the watchdog timer.

Comment: Unfortunately, on micropython 1.16 at least, the watchdog timer route is a dead end too: the maximum timeout parameter is just 8.3 seconds. And it resets the Real Time Clock although WDSEL is 0, which is unacceptable for a data logging application. Actually the hardware permits selective resets but this is not exposed by the SDK which declares [`// Reset everything apart from ROSC and XOSC`](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-sdk/blob/bfcbefafc5d2a210551a4d9d80b4303d4ae0adf7/src/rp2_common/hardware_watchdog/watchdog.c#L38)